# How to handle SerialBatchApexRangeChunkHandler Internal Salesforce.com Error in Apex Batch

Tags: salesforce, apex

I am updating few Account records in batch. But whenever the update fails due to some validation logic (in this example number is too long) the batch gets stuck in processing mode and I have to abort it manually. In the log I see Operation:SerialBatchApexRangeChunkHandler Status:Internal Salesforce.com Error. If I remove the Database.Stateful then the batch get completed but I need the error details in an email so I have to implement that.

Please help me and let me know if any more details are needed.

```
global class testBatchSettingsAndDebug implements Database.Batchable<sobject>, Database.Stateful {

    global String[] email= new String[] {'email@domain.com'};
    global List<Database.saveResult> dsrs = new List<Database.saveResult>();
    global String errorMessages {get; set;}
    global integer count=0;
    global List<String> exception_List;

    global testBatchSettingsAndDebug (){
        errorMessages ='';
    }


    //Start
        global Database.QueryLocator start (Database.BatchableContext bc){
            return Database.getQueryLocator('select id from Account limit 10');

        }    
    //Excecute
    global void execute (Database.BatchableContext bc, List<sobject> scope){
        List<Account > accToUpdateLsit = new List<Account >();//List to hold accs to update
        for (sObject objScope: scope) { 
            Account accObj = (Account )objScope ;//type casting from generic sOject to acc
            accObj.NumberofLocations__c= 123456;
            accToUpdateLsit.add(accObj);
         } 

         count=accToUpdateLsit.size();

         System.debug('Number of Records to update: '+accToUpdateLsit.size());



            if (accToUpdateLsit != null && accToUpdateLsit.size()>0) {//Check if List is empty or not
                dsrs = Database.update(accToUpdateLsit, false);
                System.debug('Records are successfully updated '+accToUpdateLsit);//Update the Records
            }




        for(Database.SaveResult dsr : dsrs){
            if(!dsr.isSuccess()){
                errorMessages += string.valueof(dsr.geterrors() + '\n'); 


           }
        }
        system.debug('Error occured: '+errorMessages);




    }

    //Finish
    global void finish (Database.BatchableContext BC){

       System.debug('**Record Updated**'+count);


       Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

      //Below code will fetch the job Id
          AsyncApexJob a = [Select a.TotalJobItems, a.Status, a.NumberOfErrors, a.JobType, a.JobItemsProcessed, a.ExtendedStatus, a.CreatedById, a.CompletedDate From AsyncApexJob a WHERE id = :BC.getJobId()];//get the job Id
          System.debug('Jobid is'+BC.getJobId());

          //below code will send an email to User about the status
          mail.setToAddresses(email);
          mail.setReplyTo('email@domain.com');//Add here your email address
          mail.setSenderDisplayName('Account Batch Notification');
          mail.setSubject('Account Batch Batch Processing '+a.Status);
          mail.setPlainTextBody('The Batch Apex job processed:  '+a.TotalJobItems+' batches with: '+a.NumberOfErrors+' failures: '+' Error Messages:'+errorMessages );
          Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.Singleemailmessage [] {mail});



       System.debug('**Job completed**');

    }
}
```

Comment: So why u just query the ID of Account but set the NumberofLocations__c field? This will not work.
Or is this just an example?

Comment: This is just an example to show the issue I am facing. In actual code it has where logic based on business logic. But the problem is same, the batch is getting stuck when there is error during the update due to some validation logic.

Comment: I had similar problems with a process (created with the process builder) that interrupts my batch. But I got an 'normal' Salesforce error and the batch stops.
The only solution in my case was to change the process in a way that it don't interfere the batch
Have u try to run it with Batchsize 1? Maybe u will get better error results

Comment: My requirement is very simple. Suppose I am updating 10 records and if 5 of them fails to update due to any validation, I want the count, record ids and errors in the email. I am not sure why it is not happening.

Comment: I understand your requirements. But from my experience Batches in Salesforce are hard to debug. So I do it always like I said: put the Batchsize to 1. Make the query as simple as possible etc. I also spend many hours in debugging Batches

Comment: I just did. Still same error.42.0 APEX_CODE,DEBUG;APEX_PROFILING,NONE;CALLOUT,NONE;DB,NONE;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,NONE;VISUALFORCE,NONE;WAVE,NONE;WORKFLOW,NONE
11:44:42.0 (499836)|USER_INFO|[EXTERNAL]|00541000000Pj0U|email@gmail.com|Pacific Standard Time|GMT-07:00
11:44:42.0 (540223)|EXECUTION_STARTED
11:44:42.0 (544316)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01p4100000NIySj|testBatchSettingsAndDebug
11:44:42.0 (146582363)|FATAL_ERROR|Internal Salesforce.com Error
11:44:42.0 (146652870)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|testBatchSettingsAndDebug
11:44:42.0 (147921329)|EXECUTION_FINISHED

Comment: @utm: Do you have any sample code that I can test  or can you please change my existing code? The issue is only happening when the batch fails to update some records.

Comment: I'll deploy your code to my Org and check if it works...

Comment: 1 strange thing: I tried to create the field NumberofLocations__c on my Account object and Salesforce tells me that this field already exists - what is definitly NOT the case

Comment: @Utm:I am really grateful to you for your help. You can create any other field. Just make sure the update fails due to some validation.

Comment: I can reproduce your problem...lets check if we can solve it

Comment: THANK GOD. As this is a very simple requirement, I believe there must be something I am missing from my side. Thanks a lot for your help. I will be waiting for your response.

Comment: OMG check this: Just found it: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000SWQXAA4&title=apex-batch-statefull-database-saveresult-with-database-error-record-s-throws-errors

Comment: @Utm:I wish I could shake your hands. It worked. I declared Database.SaveResult as transient. Worked perfectly. Do you know if this workaround compromises performance?

Comment: Sorry man no idea. Since this is a workaround - no clue about this. But if you like my answer than please do it ;) So I get some credits ;)

Comment: Please update your answer as "declare Database.SaveResult as transient". ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its seems like you just can do what is mentioned in the workard like:
Declare your Database.saveResult als transient

Comment: I can't do Database.update(accToUpdateLsit, true); as I have to accept the partial update.  I declared Database.SaveResult as transient. Worked perfectly.